# rspec simple example not working

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to learn rspec and followed what I thought was a simple example using factory girl.

spec:

```
describe Contact, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(contact).to be_valid
  end
end
```

factory girl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    full_name     { Faker::Name.name }
    email         { Faker::Internet.email }
    phone_number  { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    address       { Faker::Address.street_address }
  end
end
```

error:

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `contact' for #
   <RSpec::ExampleGroups::Contact:0x007f9b17aafc58>
```

Kind of difficult to learn if you don't have the experience to know why this if failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, with RSpec and FactoryGirl, you need to [explicitly create the factory object](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/842)

But this is a one line addition to the code you have:

```
describe Contact, type: :model do
  let(:contact) { FactoryGirl.create(:contact) }  # <-- I added this line

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(contact).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: I added that as you suggested and got this:   1) Contact has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: let(:contact) { create(:contact) }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Contact:0x007fbfddd494d8>
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28735 seconds (files took 1.93 seconds to load)
5 examples, 1 failure

Comment: Did you set up FactoryGirl per the documentation? It sounds like the create method isn't being included in the RSpec config: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: You can add `FactoryGirl.create(:contact)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add FactoryGirl.create(:contact) – Muhamad Akbar Bin Widayat